# JQuery datatable reload data for second time

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using datatables 1.10.2. I'm having problems after deleting the data and reloading another set of info via AJAX. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "classes/ajax.class.php",
        data: { 
            task: "getAllOrdersDynamic" 
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        data = data.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")  
            .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
            .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
            .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
            .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
            .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
            .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
            .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
        // remove non-printable and other non-valid JSON chars
        data = data.replace(/[\u0000-\u0019]+/g,""); 
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#dataTable").show();
        $("#esconder").hide();
        j=1;
        for(i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
          var rowIndex = $('#dataTable').dataTable().fnAddData([
              data[i].id,
              data[i].tipo_orden,
              data[i].cedula,
              data[i].nombre,
              data[i].telefono,
              data[i].fecha,
              data[i].total,
              data[i].estado,
              data[i].facturar,
              data[i].anular,
          ]);
        }

        $("#ordenDePedido").click();
    });
 });
```

Everything is fine up to this moment, but when I click on a button and do another AJAX request and try to load the info on the datatable it just dissapears

```js
$(".buscar").click(function(){
    var radioFilter = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
    var buscar = $("#buscar").val();
    var fecha_inicial = $("#fechaInicio").val();
    var fecha_final = $("#fechaFinal").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "classes/ajax.class.php",
        data: { 
            task: "getAllOrdersDynamicSearch",
            radioFilter: radioFilter,
            buscar: buscar,
            fecha_inicial: fecha_inicial,
            fecha_final: fecha_final
        }
    }).done(function(dataSearch){
        console.log(dataSearch);
        dataSearch = dataSearch.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")  
            .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
            .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
            .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
            .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
            .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
            .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
            .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
        // remove non-printable and other non-valid JSON chars
        dataSearch = dataSearch.replace(/[\u0000-\u0019]+/g,""); 
        var data = JSON.parse(dataSearch);
        
        //$("#dataTable").show();
        //$("#esconder").hide();
        j=1;

        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#dataTable")) {
          $('#dataTable').DataTable().destroy().clear();
        }

        for(i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
          console.log(id);
          $('#dataTable').dataTable().fnAddData([
              data[i].id,
              data[i].tipo_orden,
              data[i].cedula,
              data[i].nombre,
              data[i].telefono,
              data[i].fecha,
              data[i].total,
              data[i].estado,
              data[i].facturar,
              data[i].anular,
          ]);
        } 

        $("#ordenDePedido").click();
    });
```

Can someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong? I just need to clean the datatable and fill it with the new data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you destroying the table? Just empty the table and insert the new rows. If you want to speed things up and have more cleaner code you could use the built-in AJAX instead.

Comment: @davidkonrad i have tried just cleaning and also destroying it but it doesnt work either :(